# Getting Private User Record in CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am attempting to get a Users' saved data in CloudKit. I can see the record in the CloudKit Dashboard, but am unable to get to it via code in app.

```
-(void)getUserRecordID {
    CKContainer *defaultContainer =[CKContainer defaultContainer];
    [defaultContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            [defaultContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
                 self.userRecordID = recordID;
                NSLog(@"user record id: %@",recordID);
                [self getUserRecord];

            }];

       }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

}

-(void)getUserRecord {
    CKContainer *defaultContainer =[CKContainer defaultContainer];   
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase;
    [publicDatabase fetchRecordWithID:self.userRecordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *userRecord, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"current coins: %@",userRecord);


        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

This gets me the User record information, but not the ID's of the saved private records. How can I get them?

Comment: Clarify what your posted code does and doesn't do compared to what you want it to do.

Comment: It does get the User record for the current user. It does not get data saved in that users private container, nor RecordID's for the private records.

Comment: Your code makes no attempt to read other records, just the user record.

Comment: I was hoping that I would get the IDs for the private records or something. But I can't find anything in the documentation that says how to go about it...

Comment: You should read the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH1-SW1) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution. You have to query for private records using CKQuery and NSPredicate.

```
-(void)getUserRecordID {
    CKContainer *defaultContainer =[CKContainer defaultContainer];
    [defaultContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.userRecordID = recordID;
            NSLog(@"user record id: %@",recordID.recordName);
            [self getStatsRecord];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

}

-(void)getStatsRecord {
    CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
    CKReference *reference = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:self.userRecordID action:CKReferenceActionNone];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creatorUserRecordID = %@", reference];
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Stats" predicate:predicate];
    [privateDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            if (![results firstObject]) {
                [self createBlankRecord];
            }
            else {
                CKRecord *record = [results firstObject];
                NSLog(@"%@",record);
            }
        }
    }];

}
```